# Updating Multiple Pivot tables in One excel Tab using VBA to yesterday's date

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to change the date fields in a pivot table when clicking a button in excel so that across all the pivots in my tab, it is changed so it is only selecting Yesterday's date.

The line that is getting the error is:
`pf.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=dateStr`

```
Sub UpdatePivotDateFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim dateStr As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet to the "Pivots -1" tab
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivots -1")
    
    ' Calculate yesterday's date
    currentDate = Date - 1
    ' Convert to a string in the format "yyyy-mm-dd"
    dateStr = Format(currentDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    ' Loop through all pivot tables in the worksheet
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        ' Check if the pivot table has a "Date" filter field
        If pt.PageFields.Count > 0 Then
            ' Assuming the "Date" filter field is the first field in the PageFields
            Set pf = pt.PageFields(1)
            
            ' Clear all filters
            pf.ClearAllFilters
            
            ' Set the filter to yesterday's date
            *pf.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=dateStr*
        End If
    Next pt
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Using `CurrentPage` to sets the current page showing for the page field.

```vb
    ' Loop through all pivot tables in the worksheet
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        ' Check if the pivot table has a "Date" filter field
        If pt.PageFields.Count > 0 Then
            ' Assuming the "Date" filter field is the first field in the PageFields
            Set pf = pt.PageFields(1)
            ' Clear all filters
            pf.ClearAllFilters
            ' Set the filter to yesterday's date
            pf.CurrentPage = dateStr
        End If
    Next pt
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [PivotField.CurrentPage property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.currentpage?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)